# the execution sequence of Simulations is not controlled

Tags: karate

For the karate running with gatling plugin, when we specify multi Simulations in the pom like following:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
        <artifactId>gatling-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${gatling.plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <simulationsFolder>src/test/java</simulationsFolder>
            <runMultipleSimulations>true</runMultipleSimulations>
            <includes>
                <include>WorkersSimulation</include>
                <include>WorkersQuerySimulation</include>
            </includes>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

What I expect that it executes in the sequence of my sequence in the pom, WorkersSimulation first and WorkersQuerySimulation second.

But unfortunately, looks like it picks up the simulation by alphabetic sequence, WorkersQuerySimulation first and WorkersSimulation.

Sometimes we need to control the sequence of simulations, for example: create data in first simulation and test different queries in second simulation.

So is there any way to control the sequence?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a call in your main simulation itself to set up data, like in [the demo example](https://github.com/ptrthomas/karate-gatling-demo/blob/master/src/test/java/mock/CatsKarateSimulation.scala):

```
MockUtils.startServer()
```

Otherwise this is a question about the gatling maven plugin.

Comment: thanks Peter, but seems there is no concept of "main" simulation, unless I rename a simulation alphabetically in the first order. Looks like I have to use this workaround until the gatling maven plugin has a solution.

Comment: @NickHou if you are using Karate I don't understand why you need 2 simulations. can't you just have one and then refer to the feature files, the whole point of Karate's integration is to avoid writing scala as far as possible. Gatling also has before / after hooks - but there may be some limitations: https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/simulation_structure/#hooks

Comment: Hi Peter, the reason why I need more than one simulation is because there is no sequence between scenarios in one simulation, all scenarios will start in parallel. I understand that we can use nothingFor(xx seconds) to make a scenario run latter, but that can not promise it runs after another scenario. Thanks.

Comment: @NickHou do share your findings with the community !

Comment: OK, I will do the sharing.